# How to "remember" Plotly hover values in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am having trouble figuring out how Plotly's event_data("plotly_hover") function can update a value, with that value remaining static until there is a new input. I suspect Shiny's isolate({}) function could be relevant, but I'm having a really hard time figuring out how.

In my app, there are two plots: one is a Leaflet map of a flight and the other is a time series chart of measurements on the flight. [Here is a screenshot of the app,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOp9S.png) or [here is a link to the beta app.](https://zoeywerbin.shinyapps.io/flightviz/) I have the plots set up so that hovering over one will show the corresponding location on the other (a little icon on the map, and a vertical line on the chart). Hovering over either will update a time-coordinate variable ("hoverdata") shared by both. The map remembers the mouseover data; if I mouse away from it, everything stays static. But if I mouse away from the chart, Plotly's vertical line jerks back to a default location at the center (or the last map hover-input). Combined with the slowness of Plotly's hover tool, it makes for a very laggy and jerky user experience.

Here's the relevant part of the code. There's some shoddy if/else stuff going on, it's not very functional, was just trying set the default location of the vertical line to be the beginning of the plot so it wouldn't look as jerky. (I wouldn't even need that if I sort this other issue out anyways.)

```
  # get map mouseover data
  mouseover_time <- reactive ({
    user_mouseover  <- input$flightpath_shape_mouseover
    mouseoverlat <- user_mouseover$lat
    mouseoverlon <- user_mouseover$lng
    subset(flightdata(), LATITUDE==mouseoverlat & LONGITUDE==mouseoverlon)$HMStime #  get time based on mouseover coordinates
  })

  # create shared time variable (x location of plotly's vertical line)
  hoverdata <- reactive  ({
    plot_hover <- event_data(event = "plotly_hover", source = "source") # plotly mouseover
    plot_hover <- plot_hover$x[1] # get x value
    if ((is.null(d)) && (is.null(mouseover_time()))) {
    flightdata()$HMStime[flightdata()$UTC == min(flightdata()$UTC)] }  # set default as beginning of flight (does not work!)
    else if (is.null(d)) mouseover_time()   # if there's no plotly input, use map input
    else d   # otherwise use plotly input
  })
```

I really appreciate any input or help, thanks for reading this over.

Comment: I would consider using an `observe` statement rather than a `reactive` value. The reason for this is that `reactive` values use some kind of "lazy evaluation": They will be suspended when they are not actively used by the UI which can cause all kinds of troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I would recommend to use `observe` together with `reactiveValues/ractiveVal` rather than `reactive` for this task. This answer will demonstate that using some simple shiny apps. If you are interested in the theory behind reactives and when they are updated, please refer to [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

### Setup

Execute this code to load all necessary libraries and create some variables for testing

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt,mpg)) + geom_point()
ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("plot", plotlyOutput('plot')),
  tabPanel("hover data", verbatimTextOutput('text'))
))
show_message <- function(){message(Sys.time(), " updating hover_reactive")}
```

### Working version (observe/reactiveValues)

Below is an app which demonstrates a server side storage of `event_data("plotly_hover")`. The value will be updated whenever the hover data changes.

```
server1 <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(gg)
  hover_reactive <- reactiveVal()                 ## initialize
  observe({
    show_message()
    hover_data <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (!is.null(hover_data))
      hover_reactive(hover_data)                  ## set
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint({hover_reactive()})  ## get
}

shinyApp(ui, server1)
```

The `is.null` check is necessary because everytime the mouse is in the plot but not on a point, `event_data("plotly_hover")` will return `NULL`.

### Non working version (reactive)

If we try to apply a similar logic with `reactive` it will fail. The next app will print a message `[timestamp] updating hover_reactive` to the RStudio console whenever the reactive `hover_reactive` is updated. This message only appears after switching to the `hover data` tab. By that time, `event_data("plotly_hover")` will return `NULL` sice the mouse is not hovering anywhere in the plot.

```
server2 <- function(input, output, session){ 
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(gg)
  hover_reactive <- reactive({                     ## initialize/set
    show_message()
    hover_data <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (!is.null(hover_data))
      hover_data
    else
      "NA"
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint({hover_reactive()})   ## get
}

shinyApp(ui, server2)
```

The reason for this late update is that `hover_reactive` is idle until it is (directly or indirectly) displayed to the user.

### Fix of non working version

This workaround is just a reference for people with similar problems. I would not recommend using it as-is.

It is possible to prevent `hover_reactive` from becoming idle by setting it's `outputOptions`. But then, `plotly`  still sends `NULL`s whenever the mouse does not hover over any point. A backupvariable like `last_not_null_hoverdata` is therefore necessary.

```
server3 <- function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlotly(gg)
  last_not_null_hoverdata = NULL                  ## initialize
  hover_reactive <- reactive({
    show_message()
    hover_data <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (!is.null(hover_data)){
      last_not_null_hoverdata <<- hover_data      ## set
      hover_data
    }
    else
      last_not_null_hoverdata                     ## get
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint({hover_reactive()})
  ## Prevent output$text from becoming idle when it is not displayed
  outputOptions(output, "text", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server3)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! The first method you gave, using observe, worked great for both the plotly and the map hover.

Comment: I'm glad my solution worked for your setup. I just added a link to this answer in case you want to dig deeper into why `reactive`s are so lazy :)